# Viewing progress of MovieWriter file for animation plots

Tags: animation, matplotlib, simulation

I am doing simulations which can take several hours to finish and I am using `matplotlib.animation`'s `MovieWriter` to handle the details of writing plots of the data to a movie file. I am simply following the example script, http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/moviewriter.html.

Is it possible to open the movie while it is being written to? I would like to check the progress of the simulation? Maybe I need to use a video format which can operate on incomplete data stream.

I know an easy alternative is to use `savefig` simply save an image to file, but I was wondering if it is possible to "check" on the progress of the movie by making some simple changes.

When I try to open the movie while (on MacOS) I get an error basically saying that the format cannot be understood. Once fully written the file open with no problems.